# How to design a suitable low pass filter for different waveform

Tags: fpga, low-pass, dds

I want to realize a DDS signal generator based on FPGA,which is composed of FPGA,DAC and low pass filter,and the FPGA control a DAC to output different kind of signal.

Here are the system performance parameters:

- Output a signal with specific frequency, phase and amplitude.
- Output frequency range:100Hz--1MHz
- Output sine wave,triangle wave,sawtooth wave and square wave.

Here is the question:

How to design a low pass filter that is suitable for different shapes of waveform?

Comment: How square of a square wave do you desire? _Technically_, a square/triangle/sawtooth wave has infinite harmonics, and your LPF will ruin that. However, if you decide how accurate your waveforms need to be, you can work backwards from the harmonics to determine what an acceptable LPF frequency is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use multiple low pass filters and switch between them based on frequency, or have a single one with a high enough cutoff that the waves at 1MHz are not overly distorted. Your square wave would be the hardest, I would recommend using a separate circuit for it.

Update:
uint128_t Had a good explanation of how the LPF will affect your waves, also this is a case where a simple simulation could be very helpful, to visualize what a specific cutoff does to a wave.